# Localize value of variable

Tags: java, android, localization

Trying to localize the value from a variable.

```
String x = "greeting";
```

English:

```
<string name="greeting">Good morning</string>
```

Spanish:

```
<string name="greeting">Buenos dias</string>
```

I know it can be done statically like this:

```
getString(R.string.greeting);
```

But then I'm hardcoding 'greeting' where it should come from the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a new `strings.xml` file which will be localized as per the language you need. For this do the following:

1. Right click on values --> new --> Value resource file
2. File name --> strings.xml
3. In available qualifier --> Locale
4. Then select the language.

You will then get 2 separate strings file which you can write your translations